# Sort method not working in ngOnInit method

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to sort an array of objects of a class having these property -> `{ data: any, mystring: string }`

I am trying to sort like this

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.filterarray = this.unsortedarray.sort(
    (i1, i2) => i1.data.timestamp > i2.data.timestamp ? 1 : -1
  );
}
```

However, the sorting is not happening and I am getting `this.filterarray = this.unsortedarray`

If I do the same on any component (change) method (I have a select component in frontend which will help in filtering the elements from the `unsortedarray`), the sort is happening as expected. Not sure how to debug this.

All the other code lines (like data initialisation etc) is happening as expected in `ngOnInit` method.

Thanks in advance

Comment: when you log the unsortedarray before sort in ngOnInit() is it completely full?

Comment: Also i guess that sort is done inplace, it mutates the unsortedarrat

Comment: @FatemeFazli yes i checked before doing sort, the unsortedarray has all the elements.

Comment: @MarouaneFazouane filterarray is empty before sort,but filterarray becomes equal to unsorted array after running the sort, which is weird.

Comment: Please provide some sample data to work with. It would be also very helpful if you could create a working sample stackblitz replicating this issue.

Comment: is it possible to provide a demo of your code on stackblitz? if not console all variables as bellow, I think it will help you to find the issue.
`ngOnInit() {

  console.log('this.filterarray', this.filterarray);
  console.log('this.unsortedarray', this.unsortedarray);
  this.filterarray = this.unsortedarray.sort(
    (i1, i2) => i1.data.timestamp > i2.data.timestamp ? 1 : -1
  );
}`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your sorting method is called at the appropriate moment, you have to return the full difference between your timestamps, this will help for the sorting, otherwise differences returning 1 won't be differentiated amongst themselves, same for the -1.

```
this.filterarray = this.unsortedarray.sort(
    (i1, i2) => i1.data.timestamp - i2.data.timestamp
);
```